# Can we wrap an interceptor around a JAX-RS ExceptionMapper?

Tags: exception, jax-rs, interceptor

In my application, I have exception mappers for handling different exceptions. I need to somehow enforce the developers to pass the exception message from the toResponse(Exception e) method into a @RequestScoped Bean attribute for further use in the response filter chain.

Perhaps the interceptor may do the trick. However, the interceptor simply isn't getting invoked. Can someone help me understand why this is happening? Making the mapper a stateless session bean did not help either.

```
@Provider
@Interceptors(XYZInterceptor.class)
//@Stateless
public class ABCExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ABCException> {
   public Response toResponse(ABCException exception) {
      // When building response I want to force the developers to set the exception message to an attribute in a @RequestScoped Bean
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code of what you're trying to do and what isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Code would be something like this, please let me know if some more details are needed for clarity